# Force bootstrap columns of a same row to not adjust height evenly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

After reading other questions here for about 2 hours and trying my best to fix my problem, I surrender to you all.

Currently I have this:

[Actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEhkr.png)

And I want to know if it's possible to do this:

[Projected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsWAT.png)

Current grid is 3 rows, and on the second/middle one, there's 3 columns. 1st and 3rd contain 2 rows.
As you can see, I want the left and right columns to not adjust to the middle one's height.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    background-color: rgb(250, 127, 127);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
  .col-lg-8 { line-height: 200px; }
  .col-lg-12 { line-height: 80px; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Entete
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="col-lg-8">
            Section
        </section>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Pied de page
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add `h-100` to `col-lg-2`, so it only get `full` height and extra height will be blank

```css
body {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    background-color: rgb(250, 127, 127);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
  .col-lg-8 { line-height: 200px; }
  .col-lg-12 { line-height: 80px; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Entete
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 h-100">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="col-lg-8">
            Section
        </section>
        <div class="col-lg-2 h-100">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Pied de page
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I quite don't understand why setting this h-100 does fix it.
Is it telling to the browser that the column must adapt to 100% of the content, and not anything else (like the middle one's height)? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: `height: 100%` gives full height to that element and less space will ignore so, in your case, this is the best  and short solution

Comment: Works like a charm and I think I understand! ;)

Comment: Brother, here time matters, I added an answer at 19:17 and Manish added an answer at 19:34 with the same answer. so the accepted answer should be mine, so, please accept my answer as the correct answer and next time please see it before accepting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a fix height value to your row, it's possible this way (if a fix height is a option):

```css
body {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    background-color: rgb(250, 127, 127);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.fix-height {
  height: 400px;
}

.fix-height .col-lg-2,
.fix-height .row{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type="text/css">
  .col-lg-8 { line-height: 200px; }
  .col-lg-12 { line-height: 80px; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <header class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Entete
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row fix-height">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="col-lg-8">
            Section
        </section>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
                <aside class="col-lg-12">
                    Aside
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Pied de page
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one

```
.col-lg-2 {
    height: fit-content;
}
```

OR

use 
`<div class="col-lg-2 h-100">` instead of `<div class="col-lg-2">`

The .col-lg-2 was stretching its height according to its parent element, which is the row above it.

Comment: Helped me understand why the solution above worked!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's good. I believe in just giving the solution is no good for others. So I tried to explain it a bit.